# Cannot consume scoped service 'WorkshopPlanning.Data.ICalendarStatusData' from singleton 'WorkshopPlanning.Jobs.Scheduling.IScheduledTask'

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I know the question has been asked here before, but I can't seem to get it running.

I have the following in my startup.cs :

```
services.AddDbContextPool<WorkshopPlanningDbContext>(options => 
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WorkshopPlanningDb"));
        });

        //Db data
        services.AddScoped<IEmployeeData, SqlEmployeeData>();
        services.AddScoped<IPlanningData, SqlPlanningData>();
        services.AddScoped<ICalendarStatusData, SqlCalendarStatusData>();
        services.AddScoped<IMachineTypeSpecs, SqlMachineTypeSpecs>();
        services.AddScoped<IMoHistoryData, SqlMoHistoryData>();

        //Cron Jobs
        services.Configure<ProTimeConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ProTimeSftp"));
        services.AddSingleton<IScheduledTask, RetrieveProTimeData>();
        services.AddSingleton<IScheduledTask, RemoveOldProTimeData>();
        services.AddScheduler((sender, args) =>
        {
            args.SetObserved();
        });
```

My classes look as follows :

RetrieveProTimeData:

```
public class RetrieveProTimeData : IScheduledTask
{
    private readonly ICalendarStatusData _calendarStatusData;
    private readonly IOptions<ProTimeConfig> _proTimeConfig;

    public string Schedule => "10 6-18 * * *";

    public RetrieveProTimeData(ICalendarStatusData calendarStatusData, IOptions<ProTimeConfig> proTimeConfig)
    {
        this._calendarStatusData = calendarStatusData;
        this._proTimeConfig = proTimeConfig;
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the exception :

> Cannot consume scoped service 'WorkshopPlanning.Data.ICalendarStatusData' from singleton 'WorkshopPlanning.Jobs.Scheduling.IScheduledTask'

I get the exception at the following call :

```
return services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, SchedulerHostedService>(serviceProvider =>
        {
            var instance = new SchedulerHostedService(serviceProvider.GetServices<IScheduledTask>());
            instance.UnobservedTaskException += unobservedTaskExceptionHandler;
            return instance;
        });
```

And specifically at the line:

var instance = new SchedulerHostedService(serviceProvider.GetServices());

I don't know what is going wrong. It is an application I "inherited" from another developer. He doesn't know what is wrong, as he says it worked fine before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a database problem.

When I connected to our staging database, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. The exception is quite descriptive. You are registering 'WorkshopPlanning.Data.ICalendarStatusData' as 'Scoped' and 'WorkshopPlanning.Jobs.Scheduling.IScheduledTask' as a Singleton.

You cant/*shouldnt* consume 'WorkshopPlanning.Data.ICalendarStatusData' within a Singleton because of the fundamental differences between Singleton and Scoped.